# Distributing pilot iOS apps to educational institutions

Tags: ios, ios6, distribution

I'm looking for the optimal way to distribute prototype/pilot apps to K-12 institutions and I can't quite seem to figure it out.

It doesn't seem like using either the regular App Store or the Volume Purchase Program stores is ideal, as the app will only work for our pilot classrooms where the teachers have been given login credentials. Everybody else will not be able to use the app in any way, and so we'll likely get the lowest rating, if the app even makes it past review.

The two options that seem viable-ish are:

- Enterprise Distribution: it's technically not really meant for this scenario, but I've heard people use it successfully. Build the app and distribute it through the enterprise distribution flow. The problem is that technically, since we're not affiliated with the institutions we're piloting in, we'd have to have them pay $300/year and add us as contractor developers for them, something I don't envision happening. The approach I heard of was that of developers signing up for an enterprise account and using institutional devices as if they were part of that company.
- Custom B2B app: seems like one could use this route as well, even though custom B2B apps still go through an Apple review process, so I'm not clear if a prototype would get too far through the process. Also updating the app will most likely be a pain, as you have to wait for the review process to complete. It's also not clear if educational institutions are allowed to use this route.

I'm really curious to hear what your experience with either one of those has been and if you think they fit the scenario well. Is there another options I'm missing? It's especially important that the distribution flow is simple for multiple devices and allow for painless update of the apps, as we'd like to iterate as fast as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: if it's just prototype/pilot you can try AdHoc distribution.  Try https://testflightapp.com

Comment: B2B might be the best choice for the short term, just don't label it a beta. It seems unlikely Apple would reject an educational app. If the pilot succeeds, then maybe consider an enterprise license.

Comment: @user2113425 That is another good way, but you are limited 100 devices. So there is that to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might fit your needs is using TestFlight http://www.testflightapp.com. It allows you to send beta or prototype versions of your app to individual devices over the web. However, you're still limited to using Apple's provisioning and can only distribute up to 100 devices in a given year. Users will also need to provide you with their device UDID. It might be a good solution if you're only looking to have a few beta testers.

Comment: It might work, but it also might be tricky with 20+ iPads per classroom, and we have a couple of those.

Comment: In that case it probably wouldn't be the best solution. I did want to provide you with that option in the off chance you were only going to distribute to a few users.

Comment: Absolutely, much appreciated!